# Node Array - How to replacestring from values in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have created an array using custom JS in GTM for which I would like to remove strings and then add the values in the array to give me one final value.

My array has the following values

```
Array = [ [AED1,299.00], [AED2,699.00] ]
```

From this, I would like to remove "AED" and the comma so that I am left with

```
New_Array = [ [1299.00,], [2699.00] ]
```

And finally, to then add the values so that I am left with 3998.
I would like to capture this value in GTM.
However, my JS returns as undefined.

**My custom JS**

```
 function myfunction() {
   var no_products = document.querySelectorAll('span.price');

   var nodearray = [].slice.call(no_products);

   for (var i = 0; i < nodearray.length; i++) {
     nodearray[i] = nodearray[i].replace(/,/g, '');
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < nodearray.length; i++) {
     nodearray[i] = nodearray[i].replace('AED', '');
   }

    var sum = 0;
     for (var i = nodearray.length; !!i--;) {
       sum += nodearray[i]; 
     }
   return sum
 }
```

---

Using the solution that's been provided, it still returns with a 'null' value.
The issue looks to be due to the variables I had defined in the beginning which are 'no_products' and 'nodearray.'

I am trying to capture all the product prices on one of our pages I.e. there are 2 prices on the page which are AED1,299.00 and AED2,699.00.

The prices both have **span class="price"** AED1,299.00 or AED2,699.00.
And so, in GTM, I am using document.querySelectorAll('span.price') so that I can capture both prices.
And that is 'no_products.'

After capturing the two prices, I would like to put them into an array which is what the first definition of 'nodearray' is doing.
Just looking at this in the GTM preview, i see it returns a value of

[[object HTMLSpanElement], [object HTMLSpanElement]]

Would my definitions be correct?

Comment: Your first `Array` is not correct. Are they `string` inside the nested array ?

Comment: please add the value of `AED1` and `AED2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in myfunction(). You have a nested array so when you write `nodearray[0]` it doesn't return `"AED1,299.00"` but `["AED1,299.00"]`. To retrieve `"AED1,299.00"`, you have to write `nodearray[0][0]`.

See this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ugjke98k/

PS : I took the hypothesis that your Array is `[ ["AED1,299.00"], ["AED2,699.00"] ]`. If so, don't forget `"` next time you post because it's important